# Shifting positions of values in a single column

Tags: r, dataframe

This is my first question, so please let me know if I made any mistakes in the ask.

I am trying to create a dataframe which has multiple columns all containing the same values in the same order, but shifted in position. Where the first value from each column is moved to the end, and everything else is shifted up.

For example, I would like to convert a data frame like this:

```
example = data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4), y=c(1,2,3,4), z=c(1,2,3,4), w=c(1,2,3,4)
```

Which looks like this

```
x y z w
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4
```

into this:

```
x y z w
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 1
3 4 1 2
4 1 2 3
```

In the new dataframe, the "peak" or # 4 has moved progressively up in rows.

I've seen advice on how to shift columns up and down, but just replacing the remaining values with zeroes or NA. But I don't know how to shift the column up and replace the bottom-most value with what was formerly at the top.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `base R`, we can update with `Map` by removing the sequence of elements while appending values from the end

```
example[-1] <- Map(function(x, y)  c(tail(x, -y), 
        head(x, y)), example[-1], head(seq_along(example), -1))
example
#  x y z w
#1 1 2 3 4
#2 2 3 4 1
#3 3 4 1 2
#4 4 1 2 3
```

---

Or another option is `embed`

```
example[] <- embed(unlist(example), 4)[1:4, 4:1]
```